# Default bash environment changed. How do I revert it to default?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-ec2, path

I am using `AWS EC2` along with the CodeStar services.
I wanted to add the path to maven's binary to the PATH environment variable.
So I wrote it to the `/etc/environment` file and executed the command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

But it has now changed the default environment of the bash shell and now I am not able to execute any command. Even for a command like `ls` it gives output `-bash: command not found`

How do I revert back to the default settings. I tried whatever my brain could think of. But nothing helped. Would be glad to hear from the community.

Comment: Try this: `PATH="/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to revert back to the default settings:

1. As @Cyrus wrote you should update the `PATH` variable

   - In the `bash` shell run the following command:

     ```
     PATH="/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
     ```
2. Undo the changes to the `/etc/environment`

   - edit the `/etc/environment` using the same method you used before, and remove the PATH line you added to the file

You can use `sudo vi /etc/environment` or any other editor you prefer

> Note: In my AWS machine, the `/etc/environment` file is empty.